# Script wont call function in Google Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a script that pops up a div element when a anchor tag is clicked

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="popup(\'yme-property-pop\'); loadproperties(\'open\', \''.$row['id'].'\');"><h2>' . $row['placename'] . '</h2></a>';
```

It's echoed from a PHP script, and is working fine in FF and IE(9).
But chrome won't run it, atleast on ver. 18.0.1025.168 m

The popup(divid); event fires when I click it, but it doesent complete the function calling inside the script the function is in.

```
            var width_ratio = 0.4; // If width of the element is 80%, this should be 0.2 so that the element can be centered

    function toggle(div_id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
        if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
        else {el.style.display = 'none';}
    }
    function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
                    alert(popUpDivVar);
        if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
            viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
        } else {
            viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
            blanket_height = viewportheight;
        } else {
            if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
                blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
            } else {
                blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
            }
        }
        var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
        blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
        var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
        popUpDiv_height=0;
        popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
    }
    function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
        if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
            viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
        } else {
            viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
            window_width = viewportwidth;
        } else {
            if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
                window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
            } else {
                window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
            }
        }
        var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
        window_width=window_width/2;
        window_width = window_width * width_ratio; 
        popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
    }
    function popup(windowname) {
                    alert(windowname); // THIS WORKS
        blanket_size(windowname);
        window_pos(windowname);
        toggle('blanket');
        toggle(windowname);     
    }
```

The last function in that script is the one that is called first. I put an alert box in it to verify that it was fired. BUT, I put an alert box in the next function that it calls (blanket_size), and it did not fire, as I had the alert box on the first line in the function. It did not fire.

I simply have no clue why. The weird thing is that this stuff works in other browsers, but not chrome. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit:** And I also verified that the parameter value passed into the popup() function (the 'windowname' param) is valid/has a value. It contains the ID of a DIV that is in the HTML document, and it's not dynamically created.

**Edit 2:** Ok, I got the script running when and ONLY when I add an alert box with the parameter value in it (windowname) to the popup(windowname) function. But if I remove that box, it stops working again.

**Edit 3:**
Got no errors on the debugger at all. But now I'm even more confused. After a great deal of tries, it seems like it's working with the alert box at random! Sometimes works, and sometimes not.

**Final Edit**
Changed logic to jQuery. Should have done this long ago!

```
    // Open property
$(".property-open-link", ".yme-propertyitem").live('click', function() { 
    $("#yme-property-pop").css({'display': 'block', 'z-index': '9999' });
    $("#blanket").css({'display': 'block', 'height', getBlanketHeight(), 'z-index': '1000' });
    loadproperties('open', $(this).closest(".yme-propertyitem").attr("id"));
});
// Close property button
$("#yme-property-close").live('click', function() { 
    $("#yme-property-pop").css('display', 'none');
    $("#blanket").css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using chrome debug console (F12)? It will show you if there is any error in your script.

Comment: Hi! Yes, there seems to be no error. Plus, like I said it works in other browsers, so it should not be a fatal error at that.

Comment: Your problem may lie here: `onclick="popup(\'yme-property-pop\'); loadproperties(\'open\', \''.$row['id'].'\');"`. Try to get rid of `\ ` from js part - simple `echo "onclick=\"popup(''); ... \""` may fix this.

Comment: Could you show us the code _with_ the alerts? Also, do you get any errors in the debug console of Chrome?

Comment: Try adding `debugger;` at the beginning of the `popup` function, it will allow you to debug effectivly (using F10 to pass from line to line and gattering information on method parameters by using mouseover)

Comment: Hey. Got no errors on the debugger at all. But now I'm even more confused. After a great deal of tries, it seems like it's working with the alert box at random! Sometimes works, and sometimes not... I also tried that change h4b0, but it didn't change anything unfortunatly. I also added the alert() I added in the script, in the original post above so you can see that.

Comment: The only "error" when I put the debugger; on in the popup function, is that it goes down to the function it should fire, and then it just finishes up (it does not move to the function in debugger mode, it just goes back to normal).

Comment: Got some progress: My page is for some reason loading widdit.com (some search / autocomplete stuff that I guess google chrome uses for forms or whatnot). As long as it says in the statusbar: "loading loading1.widdit.com", the popup stuff works. But just as it finishes, it does not work anymore. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to clear up first:

1. It really helps if you create [a way for us to interact with your
   code](http://jsfiddle.net), especially as you've pasted PHP code here, instead of plain
   HTML
2. Is there a reason why you're [not using a library](http://jquery.com) to handle your DOM
       interactions? It will make your code more concise and take away some
       possible failure points when it comes to cross-browser code.

Right,

I'm a little unsure why your code isn't working in Chrome. I [set up a demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blink/TmNaW/) and it seems to work fine.

You'll notice I'm not attaching the events in `onclick` attributes on the `<a/>` element, and neither should you. This could be where the problem lies.

Currently, the code in the jsfiddle alerts as expected and only fails when it fails to find a relevent DOM node in toggle.

Note:

`addEventListener` in the example is not cross-browser, which is another reason to use a DOM library.

Comment: I am using jQuery across the whole site actually. But that popup script is something I found and edited a bit. But now I got sick of it and changed that to jQuery as well, as I should have done long ago to be consistent with what lib I use. So, in other words, this answer is the correct one. Thank you for the additional info here as well!